# Get true location of "Desktop" folder

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I have observed that if you press <strike>backlash</strike>  backspace several times in Explorer you get a folder with extra items on it. That includes network drives, Home, personal user folder, libraries and so. Not the regular C:\users(username)\desktop folder. I would like to create a shortcut to this folder because it seems more useful

Comment: It's not clear what your asking, a shortcut to your Desktop, already exists within File Explorer.  You should [edit] you question to clarify it.

Comment: It is unclear if you are on a network.  Normally C:\Users\username\Desktop is the location in all properly setup Windows.

Comment: Backslash, backspace or backlash?

Comment: Backspace* . Excuse the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a shortcut to the virtual Desktop, the root of the [Shell namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro). To create a shortcut to this folder that bheaves like a "normal" shortcut to a folder -- navigating the current folder to the shortcudt target rather than opening a new window with an **Explorer** command, you can't use the shortcut wizard, but you can create it with a few lines of **PowerShell** code.

You can copy and paste the following block of code into a **PowerShell** window. It will create the shortcut in whatever directory the window is open to.

```
$LnkFile = (New-Object -com wscript.shell).CreateShortcut(('{0}\Desktop.lnk' -f $PWD.Path))
$LnkFile.TargetPath  = "KnownFolder:{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}"
$LnkFile.Description = "Virtual Desktop"
$LnkFile.Save()
```

Answer (score 2):

When I press backspace several times in Explorer I get to `shell:Desktop`.

You can use that shell folder command also in shortcuts:
`explorer shell:Desktop`